# Reverse array function with one parameter. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm having a problem trying to write a body for a function that recursively reverse an array, but only has one parameter.

```
function ReverseArray(arr) {

  var i = 0;
  var j = arr.length - 1;

  if (i < j) {
    var temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
    return ReverseArray(arr);
  }

  return arr;
}
```

I realize this won't work because the variables will be re-initialized when the function calls itself.

I'm just looking for some ideas at this point, because i'm stuck.

Comment: Create a temporary array with the same length and fill this up while looping through your original array. After the loop set your original array to the new array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164039/javascript-recursion

Comment: Where does the 1 argument limitation come from?

Comment: @zerkms Homework, probably. This question has been asked multiple times.

Comment: @zerkms: I'm going to guess homework. There's simply no other reason for such an arbitrary restriction. Wonder if you could cheat by using `arguments`?

Comment: @Matt Burland: I realize it's homework. I just didn't expect it to be that silly

Comment: @zerkms: A while back I asked [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266979/contrived-homework-questions) on Meta.

Answer (score 2):

First, for other people who might be looking to reverse an array for a *real* problem rather than homework, use [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), don't waste you time trying to implement it yourself.

If you absolutely must, then the trick here would be to pass a smaller array (minus the first and last elements by using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) when you recurse and rebuild the final array as you unwind using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). For example:

```js
function ReverseArray(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return arr;
  } else {
    var first = arr[0];
    var last = arr[arr.length - 1];
    return [last].concat(ReverseArray(arr.slice(1, length - 1))).concat([first]);
  }

}

alert(ReverseArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Comment: With one argument it's really ugly. And looks completely useless for education (+1)

Comment: Btw, try `ReverseArray([1])`

Comment: You're overcomplicating it. Else case could be `var first = arr.pop(); return [first].concat(ReverseArray(arr));`

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Array.reverse](http://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method.

Anyways... for testing/learning purposes:

```
["a","b","c"].map(function(v,i,a) {return a[a.length-i-1]})
```

**v** is value, **i** is iteration, and **a** is array.

1st iteration:

v="a"; i=0; a=["a","b","c"];

2nd iteration:

v="b"; i=1; a=["a","b","c"];

3rd iteration:

v="c"; i=2; a=["a","b","c"];

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to write your own reverse method? Why not just use the reverse method on the array?

```
function ReverseArray(arr) {
    arr = arr.reverse();
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above method obviously does not make a lot of sense anymore since you can just call the reverse method wherever you want.

Comment: Why to even wrap it then? And obviously OP learns some FP (or similar) practices

Comment: OP is asking for a recursive solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the following solution is the simplest recursive implementation:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
alert(ReverseArray(a));

function ReverseArray(arr) {
    if(arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    } else {
        return [arr.pop()].concat(ReverseArray(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using shift, pop, unshift, and push to avoid making partial copies of the array.  Probably a tad bit faster than copying of part of the array using slice on each recursive call, but don't expect it to outperform a non-recursive solution or the built-in reverse method:

```
function recReverse(list){
  if(list.length>=2){
    var lo=list.shift();
    var hi=list.pop();
    list=recReverse(list);
    list.unshift(hi);
    list.push(lo);
  }
  return list;
}
```

and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jongobar/19ryj8nm/)

Answer (score -1):

Say you have an array [1 2 3 4 5]

Simply store the last number somewhere, and feed 1-4 into the function again (resulting in 5-1234)

When there is only one number in the fed in array, return that number as a single array member.

When the array is returned back, append the returned array to the temporary number into a new array.

This should do 4-123, then 3-12, then 2-1, which will all feed back up, resulting in 5-4-3-2-1

Condensed version:

```
var input_array = [1,2,3,4,5]

function rev(input) {
  if (input.length == 1) { return input; }
  if (input.length == 0) { return []; }
  return [input[input.length-1]].concat(rev(input.splice(0, input.length-1)));
}

rev(input_array);
```

Spread out version:

```
var input_array = [1,2,3,4,5]

function rev(input) {
  if (input.length == 1) { return input; }
  if (input.length == 0) { return []; }
  var last = [input[input.length-1]];
  var newarr = rev(input.splice(0, input.length-1));
  var answer = last.concat(newarr);
  return answer;
}

rev(input_array);
```

Comment: No, you don't want to return a number, but an array. Also, "*when there is only one number*" is **not** the base case.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant. Editted to reflect that. Return it as [1], not as 1. Actually, it could still work with that, if you check if its the type on return, but checking length would be smarter than checking type.

Comment: Your function is still failing on the empty array.

Answer (score -1):

what you need to do is this

```
function reverse(x, i, j) {
    if (i < j) {//Swap
        var tmp = x[i];
        x[i] = x[j];
        x[j] = tmp;
        reverse(x, ++i, --j);//Recursive
    }
}

function reverseIt(x) {
    console.log(x);
    reverse(x, 0, x.length - 1);
    console.log(x);
}


var q = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
reverseIt(q);
```

Comment: then try local storing tempvalues in local storage

Comment: "storing tempvalues in local storage" --- you are missing the whole point

Answer (score -1):

```
function reverseArray(origArray)
{
    if (origArray.length > 1) {
        var element = origArray[0];
        var newArray = reverseArray(origArray.slice(1));
        newArray[newArray.length] = element;
        return newArray;
    } else {
        return origArray;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `[]` is a valid array actually

Comment: Where does `element` come from in that `origArray.length == 1` case? And what do you need that case for at all?