# Recursive Array Reversal Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

So we are practicing functional javascript in my programming class with this assignment and I just can't get it to work right. Any advice in making this code work would be appreciated. Everything but the body was given for me to use. Here is what I have come up with:
(It is always sending me just the first array index content rather than all of them reversed. I tried changing it to

```
 if(arr.length <= 1) return arr;
```

but that never hits the base case.)

```
function ReverseArray(arr) {

//base case

if(arr.length == 1)
{
   return arr[0];
}
if(arr.length == 0)
{
   return 0;
}

var head = arr.pop;
var newArr = [head, ReverseArray(arr)];
return newArr;
}
```

Comment: if(arr.length = 1) WRONG and if(arr.length = 0) wrong, You are assigning

Comment: Deleted my answer because I realised you were meant to use recursion.

Comment: Even if your function worked, your function returns an array so after one iteration, you'll have this `[end0, [....]]`.  After two iterations, you'll have this `[end0, [end1, [...]]]` and it will keep nesting arrays further and further.  Your approach will not work.  You need a new design.  Perhaps you want to use `.concat()` to add two arrays together rather than embedding one in another.  If you want help with a new design, you will have to better describe the rules of the assignment since `arr.reverse()` already exists to do this.

Comment: `if (arr.length < 2) return arr;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse array function with one parameter. (JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836808/reverse-array-function-with-one-parameter-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = y <--assignment
z == y <-- comparison
```

Looking at your code:

```
if(arr.length = 1)
```

needs to be

```
if(arr.length == 1)
```

same with the zero check

---

AND you are not calling pop

```
var head = arr.pop;
```

you need to parenthesis

```
var head = arr.pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a runnable example with a working function. FYI there is also a [built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function that will do this for you.

I think other than the confusion with assignment/comparison operators, when you were building the result array, you should be using [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to concatenate your array, instead you were building a new array where the second item was an array itself.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(ReverseArray(a));

function ReverseArray(arr) {
    if(arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    } else {
        return [arr.pop()].concat(ReverseArray(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most precise and clean way to do it in a single line with the ternary operator.

```
function reverse(arr) {
  return arr.length < 2 ? arr : [arr.pop()].concat(reverse(arr));
}
console.log(reverse([4, 3, 3, 1]));
```